# No output from javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am really new to programming and this has had me stumped for days. I'm trying to do a really simple postage calculator. The function on its own works fine but when I tried to link it to user input im getting no output. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Here's what I have been trying..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>
        <title>postage calculator</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-     scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Postage Calculator</div>


<input id="amount" type="text" name="purchasePrice" placeholder="0" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
<script type="text/javascript">

var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

function aberdeen(){
    var weight = parseFloat(amount.value) || 0;
                if(weight>0 && weight<500){

                        return total = 3.50;

                }
                else if(weight<501 && weight<750){

                       return total = 4.30;
                   }
                else if(weight<751 && weight<1000){

                       return  total = 5.10;
                   }
               else if(weight<1001 && weight<1250){

                   return total = 5.90;
               }
                   else if(weight<1251 && weight<1500){

                       return total = 6.70;
                   }
                   else if(weight<1501 && weight<1750){

                       return total = 7.50;
                   }
                   else if(weight<1751 && weight<2000){

                       return total = 8.30;
                    }
                else{
                    return 0;
                }
            }
submit.addEventListener("click", aberdeen, false);
</script>
    </body>
          </html>
```

Comment: Where is your code supposed to give output? You want to display the value of "total"?

Comment: Think of your page as a dummy, if you don't tell it where or what you want the value to return to then it won't... This is the point of programming, you tell it what you want it to do and it will do it.

Comment: `weight<501 && weight<750` ? You probably meant `weight > 500 && weight <= 750` right ?

Comment: Yeah that makes much more sense! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to have element that will have the output of the calulation like:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
   output.innerHTML = aberdeen();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the eventListeners after the elements you are listening to are loaded.
The output has to be displayed somewhere. It can be either displayed in a textbox, a HTML-element or a simply alert() -box. I have used a text box in my example using  element.

Also I created a working version of your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>
        <title>postage calculator</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-     scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Postage Calculator</div>


<input id="amount" type="text" name="purchasePrice" placeholder="0" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
<input id="userPays" type="text" name="userPays" />
<script type="text/javascript">



function aberdeen(amount){
    var weight = parseFloat(amount) || 0;
    if(weight>0 && weight<500){

        return 3.50;

    }
    else if(weight<501 && weight<750){

        return 4.30;
    }
    else if(weight<751 && weight<1000){

        return 5.10;
    }
    else if(weight<1001 && weight<1250){

        return 5.90;
    }
    else if(weight<1251 && weight<1500){

        return total = 6.70;
    }
    else if(weight<1501 && weight<1750){

        return 7.50;
    }
    else if(weight<1751 && weight<2000){

        return 8.30;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}



window.onload = function() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    var userPays = document.getElementById("userPays");

    function count(){
        userPays.value = aberdeen(amount.value);
    }

    submit.addEventListener("click", count, false);
}
</script>
    </body>
          </html>
```

See demo at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxaaQe

Make sure your logic to calculate values is correct as some commenters have suggested.

Comment: I cant believe I didnt even consider actually putting the output somewhere!   Rookie mistake! Thank you all for your help it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere ;) If mine answer solves correctly your problem, please feel free to vote it up!